# PFSense Different Gateway for different Hosts

Tags: routing, gateway, pfsense

I have a firewall software currently in use, however I am looking at replacing this with PfSense.
I am looking to effectively replicate some of the settings on the current firewall we have in place.

The wall I have hit comes to routing hosts via a specific gateway. The current software we use has the ability to simply supply a source IP and then select the gateway that will be used. Job done, go to wimi and the change is immediate. I need to do the same thing with PfSense as I have four interfaces. 3 Wan and 1 Lan.

The 3 WAN connections have static IP's within the range of the routers they are connected to and the default gateway is WAN1. When accessing wimi.com I correctly receive the WAN IP of the WAN1 Gateway router, so this side of things is working correctly.

I need to statically route a few people through WAN2 and then WAN3 is dedicated for scripts etc (so this interface will just be a few firewall rules).

So my question is how I can specify a network IP on the LAN and set which gateway is used to connect to the internet. I can see in System->Gateways Route tab, I can add a Host (I am doing this by Alias) and then select a Gateway. When doing this however, I locked myself out fo the LAN and was unable to ping/access the PfSense gui. After disabling the rule access returned. Have I misunderstood this section and if so how do I go about achieving this.

As a note I can't say use load balancing as I need to test certain services and I must originate from a specific IP. Therefore my machine would have to be routed through WAN2 90% of the time, unless I need to switch to test another service.

Many thanks

**Update**
Please see requested information:

Here is a collection of screenshots from the various pages.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG6Xj.jpg

I have two machines connected 
172.26.0.10
172.26.0.11

CPE is currently the default Gateway and machines are showing the correct IP when visting wimi. I need to route my machine (172.26.0.10) v ia the ADSL gateway, however, the ip on wimi and the tracert show the same as all other machines.

I have treble checked the NIC ip, made sure to release and renew at every change etc and close re-open cmds before executing the tracert again. I have also rebooted the pfsense server a few times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a rule to your LAN interface that matches traffic coming from/going to certain hosts/nets as required and specify the outgoing gateway in that rule.

Comment: Forgive me for being a bit thick here. I have removed the Default Gateway rules, and have now tried to do as you said. I have clicked Firewall->Rules and added a rule under any circumstance for my pc ip and selected the WAN2 gateway and saved the rule. I have added the rule in the lan and also the floating rules separately. regardless I seem to be getting WAN1 Ip when going to wimi and also getting the WAN1 gateway ip when doing a tracert.

Comment: How about just posting the rules? "added a rule under any circumstance for my PC IP" is pretty vague.

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot and some info. Anything I have left out or you need to know, just let me know and I'll get it ASAP. Many thanks for your time so far.

Comment: Ok so as it turns out I'm a moron. I had  a squid proxy on so I was blocking all traffic to websites and the second round of testing I did was using tracert not wimi. By changing the rule to all instead of TCP/UDP it is now working. I did not spot this before, rookie mistake, many thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh good. By the screenshots you posted I thought "well crap, looks right to me!"

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a rule under **Firewall > Rules > LAN**

Make the below entries;

Action > Pass

Interface > LAN

Address Family > *Your Choice*

Protocol > *Your Choice*

Source > Single Host or alias > *Your Host IP*

Destination > any

Click **Display Advanced** under **Advanced Options**

Scroll Down to **Gateway** and select your preferred Gateway to go through.

Click **Save** and you are ready...

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I changed the Protocole from `any` to `TCP/UDP`. My firewall is OPNsense 21.1